# I have an (x, y) coordinate (int8_t) and need to rotate them by "x" degrees relative to (0, 0) in C (no access to floats or Math lib)

Tags: c, math, geometry, trigonometry, angle

I'm working in C on a MCU that has no floating points or Math library, and the largest type I have is `int32_t`.

I have an `(x, y)` coordinate (`int8_t`) on a graph like this:

[image: x, y graph with labelled axis and a single point at (32, -64)]

A user can say that they want to rotate the location of the point by `X` degrees (let's say `90°`). This is always relative to the center.

The end result should be `(64, 32)`:

[image: x, y graph with labelled axis and a single point at (64, 32)]

I need to implement this in C with no access to the Math library (no atan2, sin, etc.) The precision I need is in `0.2°` increments (so `0.2°`, `40.8°`, etc. are all valid.)

Comment: "to implement this in C with no access to the Math library" --> post what you have tried, else it sounds like you are asking others to write code for you for free.

Comment: A lookup table of one trig function for 360/0.2 values wouldn't be huge even if you used 32 bit types. You'd only need one function (sin, cos or tan) to do the rotation.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have no background in mathematics and the more I Google, the less and less I'm finding - I have no implemented solutions.

Comment: @ZachB I'd be very open to some sort of lookup table but I'm working in some pretty limited conditions (only have 64kb of RAM to work with.)

Comment: You can use a lookup table (450 fixed-point int32_t), or a piecewise linear approximation (smaller lookup table, more code), or a taylor series (no lookup table, tricky code) to compute the necessary sin/cos values. Then it's just fixed-point multiply, add, and subtract.

Comment: Thanks @user3386109! Those terms give me something to Google and look into now :) I really appreciate the breakdown of those 3!

Comment: @tshiono I am a web developer originally. I am making my own hardware adapter now though at https://keyboard.gg and this is just one of the road bumps I've hit. I have reassessed my life and think I will continue onwards in this pursuit. Google has taught me enough in these past 10 years :)

Comment: I see, good luck! I still recommend you to study math even now. It will surely be your asset in life. Cheers.

Comment: Take a look at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix
If you don't have access to math libs, you can compute sine and cosine using the Taylor series expansions:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: Another keyword to use a starting point: "fixed point arithmetic". You can use 32 bit integer arithmetic to do some limited floating point calculations. Make sure you understand it, before you use it.

Comment: This would be why we are supposed to do: 1) write down project requirements 2) outline the design 3) pick a suitable MCU. And not 1) pick a random MCU like some Arduino found in a packet of corn flakes 2) try to shoehorn the completely unsuitable MCU into some project requirements.

Comment: Anyway, the keyword you are looking for is "fixed point trigonometry". And implementing it/understanding it will be far more math-intense than simply doing this with math.h and floating point. The simple solution is to get a Cortex M4 with FPU and then just code away.

Comment: You could try [CORDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) - it computes both sine and cosine simultaneously which is useful for rotations.

Answer (score 1):

OP is looking for a full circle non-`math.h` [`atan2()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Solve a simpler problem first.  Find the [*arctangent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions) of [0.0 to 1.0] with a "precision I need is in 0.2° increment".  The result would be [0.00 ... 45.00] degrees or *at least* 45/0.2 (225) different values.

In the range 0 to 45 degrees, the arctangent(x) function curves gently.  It slope (in radians/x) is near 1.0 when x == 0 to about 0.6187... at x=45 degrees.  Is is sufficient to make a uniform lookup table of about 225/0.6187 (364) entries to achieve precision of 0.02 degrees.

Form the look-up table `arctan_lu[SCALE_INDEX + 1]` with pre-calculated values `round(radians2degrees(atan(1.0*index/SCALE_INDEX))*100.0)` from say, Excel or another C program.

```
// Number of table lookup entries
#define SCALE_INDEX 364
const int arctan_lu[SCALE_INDEX + 1] = { 0, ..., 4500 };  // Values from pre-computation
```

Then scale the lookup index and lookup the answer.

```
// Return arc-tangent in centi-degrees [0 ... 4500]
// for an x, y in the first octant:  0 < y < x < INT32_MAX/SCALE_INDEX
// 
int arctagent_primary(int32_t y, int32_t x) {
  int index = SCALE_INDEX*y/x;
  return arctan_lu[index];
}
```

Now armed with a solution for the first octant, manipulate `x,y` for the other octants.

```
// Return arctangent in centi-degrees [0 ... 36000]
// for all x, y
unsigned arctagent_primary(int32_t y, int32_t x) {
  if (y < 0) {
    return 36000 - arctagent_primary(-y, x);
  }
  if (x < 0) {
    return 18000 - arctagent_primary(y, -x);
  }
  if (y >= x) {
    return 9000 - arctagent_primary(x, y);
  }
  if (y > 0) {
    retrun arctagent_primary(y, x);
  }
  return 0; // x,y both 0
}
```

Additional work needed in `arctagent_primary()` when `x` or `y` are greater than `INT32_MAX/SCALE_INDEX`.  Simply scale them down together.

```
while (x > INT32_MAX/SCALE_INDEX || y > INT32_MAX/SCALE_INDEX) {
  x /= 2;
  y /= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a pre-computed lookup table for the first quadrant of sin(x).

Since you need 0.2° degrees precision, that would be 450 values in the table. Keep them as int32 fixed-point, with 16 bits fractional part.

If you have that table, you can use 16.16 fixed point math to compute 2x2 [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), and multiply your point by the matrix.

If you have many points to rotate by the same angle, will probably be faster than the arctangent. Transforming a point with that matrix only takes 4 shifts (two for input, two on output), 4 int32 multiplications, and 2 int32 additions.

P.S. If you really low on memory, use 17.15 fixed point instead of 16.16, this way the lookup table only needs 2 bytes/entry, 900 bytes for the complete table.